# killing threads from main

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am a bit new to threading as I have never needed it on an advanced level up until now.

I have the following problem I need to solve:

I have an application where you specify how many threads it should work with, and after that you get it to start.

I know this can be done with ThreadPool but I need a bit more functionality, I don't know how to make it so it makes a callback when all the threads are done and a function to stop all threads and queues if needed.

One idea was making a new thread and working with the threadpool from there so that when I kill that threat it kills are the ones started from that thread (being the main). Also that way I'd be able to set it to call back (the single thread) when the queue is cleared.

Comment: showing some code would be nice

Comment: I am not sure about the structure or i would post the code. i need to queue 100 tasks, and work with 10 threads, and get a callback when those are done to main thread (some funct)

Comment: It depends on the tasks that these threads are trying to accomplish. If all these threads are divvying up a task, then it sounds like a good candidate for the Producer-Consumer queue.

Comment: Also, check out this guide to threading. It's awesome: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: could you direct me to some good read to investigate further on this?

I am not sure about the structure or i would post the code. i need to queue 100 tasks, and work with 10 threads, and get a callback when those are done to main thread (some funct)

is what i need basically

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Try these: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Pulse_Producer_Consumer_Queue or for a simpler example http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_WaitHandle_Producer_Consumer_Queue

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Task`s and `CancellationToken`s:

```
        var taskCount = 10;
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount ; i++)
        {
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // do work here.

                // Also periodically check 
                if( cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested )
                    return;

                // or wait on wait handle
                cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        // to cancel all threads 
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

The number of threads running concurrently is managed for you by the ThreadPool within the TaskFactory, based on your machine's reported CPU cores. If you want more control, it is possible to provide your own custom TaskFactories I believe.